# How To Protect Tomcat 7 Against Slowloris Attack

Tags: security, tomcat, denial-of-service

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7 to run my webapp on Linux. I scanned it by Acunetix and it's telling me that my webapp is vulnerable to "Slow HTTP Denial of Service Attack". How can I protect it?

Acunetix is reffering me to [here](http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/08/protect-apache-slowloris-attack/), but it's about securing Apache, not Tomcat.